# Using bash/terminal to get battery draining apps

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, bash, battery, catalina

I have the following Macbook Pro model.

[image: macbookpro-info]

I would like to find the apps that are consuming considerable power from the terminal so that I can kill them if I am on battery power.

All searches so far yield results referring to GUI or `clicky-bunty` solutions.

I would like to run a shell script to find those power hungry apps and terminate them.

I currently populate a bash array then run something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

kill_apps=(\
    Slack \
    Docker \
)

ac_power="$(ioreg -l | grep ExternalConnected | cut -d"=" -f2 | sed -e 's/ //g')"

if [[ "${ac_power}" == "No" ]]; then
    for app in "${kill_apps[@]}"; do
        eval "osascript -e 'quit app \"${app}\"'"
    done
fi
```

I am sure I can do better?

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/nnethercote/2015/08/26/what-does-the-os-x-activity-monitors-energy-impact-actually-measure/